# Get Object ID in nfcpy Library (python)

Tags: python, linux

I use the following Library to read an NFC Smart Card: https://github.com/nfcpy/nfcpy

```
tag = clf.connect(rdwr={'on-connect': lambda tag: False})
print(tag)
```

I get the following Output, wenn I scan a card:

```
Type2Tag ID=*censored*
```

I need the "ID" of this Object as a string. But don't know ho to get it, I am very new to Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the string you have now, split it using the 'ID=' substring as the separator, and capture the portion that's the ID.

`tag_id = str(tag).split('ID=')[1]`

Comment: Thanks! Work for me.